# Getting a fixed amount of data in a certain order from an array

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, deep-learning, resize

I have 1100 arrays of different sizes. Some array size is 44 and some is 26. My minimum array size is 19. So I want to make them all in the same size. I will get 19 data from each array. And I have to get them in a certain order. For example, this is very easy when I have a 38 size array. Since 38/19 = 2, I can get the data regularly in steps of 2. But how should I proceed when the size of the array is 44 or 33.

Comment: Maybe round (or floor) the index after adding the step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @beaker already proposed I recommend selecting the entries by rounding, so to achieve the behaviour you mentioned when the numbers divide evenly you could use this

```
function ind = sample(cnt, len)
ind = linspace(1, len+1, cnt+1);
ind = round(ind(1:end-1));
end
```

Here `sample` returns the indices taht can then be used to sample from that array, `cnt` is the amount of samples you want and `len` is the length of the array you want to sample from.

Comment: This is spot on for what I was needing. Thank you so much.

Comment: And May I ask why you are using len + 1 and cnt + 1 instead of using len and cnt directly?

Comment: @pekolas `linspace` creates a vector that includes the start and end value, but you said you'd want to take every *other* value if the lengths divide evenly, like `0,2,4,6` if you want to sample 4 from a list `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`. This means we need to discard the last value (`ind(1:end-1)`) and compensating that by using `len+1` and `cnt+1`. To get a feeling what's going on just remove these `+1` from the code and see what you get!